# How to change navigation back button color from button tap

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uisplitviewcontroller, back

I use a `UISplitViewController` and I change the back button color whenever showing the detail view through:

```
/* In ParentVC */

let backButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "", style: .plain, target: self, action: nil)
backButton.tintColor = .red
self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = backButton

let vc = DetailVC()
self.splitViewController?.showDetailViewController(vc, sender: nil)
```

From inside the `DetailVC` the user is able to tap on a button to change the color of the VC, but the back button color is not changing. I found I can change the back button color by doing:

```
/* In DetailVC */

if let parentVC = self.splitViewController?.viewControllers.first?.children.first as? ParentVC {
     parentVC.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem?.tintColor = getNewColor()
}
```

However, the back button's color doesn't change to the first color chosen **until** the user taps the color change button a second time. It's always one tap behind, so if I choose a different color every time, it will always be set to the previous color.

**Does anyone know how to force reload the navigation bar's back button?** Or knows why this is happening?

Thank you in advance!